# How to load html text in watchkit WKInterfaceLabel in ios?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, watchkit, nsattributedstring

I have on WKInterfaceLabel in which i can not load HTML Tag like

```
<h1>Grishneshwar Jyotirling</h1>
```

and I can't use **NSMutableAttributedString** so please help me to finding regarding things.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var htmlText = "<h1>Grishneshwar Jyotirling</h1> Grishneshwar Jyotirling"
    let attributeText: NSAttributedString?

    if let htmlData = htmlText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding) {

        do {

            attributeText  =  try   NSAttributedString(data: htmlData , options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
            myLabel.setAttributedText(attributeText)

        }catch let e as NSError {
            print("Couldn't translate \(htmlText): \(e.localizedDescription) ")
        }
```